# How is it possible to share a popwindows between 2 activities

Tags: android, android-activity, share, popupwindow

I have a single popupWindows that works well when I call it in the activity. But my idea is to set specific class for this popupWindows and call it by different activities. How is-it possible ?

My popupWindows class

```
public class GestionCat extends PopupWindow
```

{
    Context     m_context;

```
public GestionCat(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    m_context = context;

    setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(context).
         inflate(R.layout.cat, null));

    setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

public void show(View anchor)
{
    showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

}

And how I call it :

```
Activity activity = this.getParent();
View view = activity.findViewById(R.layout.main_layout);
Context context =  getApplicationContext();
GestionCat gestionCat = new GestionCat(context ); 
gestionCat.show(view);
```

thank for help

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the creation of a singleton. In your GestionCat class you want the following code:

```
private GestionCat _gestionCat;

public static GestionCat getInstance()
{
    if(_gestionCat == null)
    {
        _gestionCat = new GestionCat();
    }

    return _gestionCat;
}
```

Now you can use `GestionCat.getInstance()` every time to get the same instance of the GestionCat that you are looking for. That way you can share the popup window in multiple classes.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx for more information.